# Gradient Semi Circle

Tags: ios, swift

I want to draw semi circle with gradient, but when i add gradient the semi circle does not look right

what i have done

```
let center = CGPoint(x: circleView.bounds.size.width / 2, y: circleView.bounds.size.height / 2)
let circleRadius = circleView.bounds.size.width / 2
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)

let semiCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
semiCircleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
semiCircleLayer.lineCap = .round
semiCircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
semiCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
semiCircleLayer.lineWidth = 6
semiCircleLayer.strokeStart = 0
semiCircleLayer.strokeEnd  = 1

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

gradient.frame = circleView.bounds
gradient.mask = semiCircleLayer

circleView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Gradient Semi Circle:

[image: Gradient Semi Circle]

Without Gradient Semi Circle:

[image: Without Gradient Semi Circle]

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: "the semi circle does not look right" In what sense?

Answer (score 0):

its because you're using full frame of initial circleView and lineWidth > 1

try to change this line

```
let circleRadius = circleView.bounds.size.width / 2 - 4
```